# same tangent lines

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

[image]

I have a feeling I is correct by drawing graphs. But can't really argue rigorously. Any thoughts would be appreciated!Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x>0$, then $\frac{f(x)}x\geqslant\frac{g(x)}x$; therefore, since $f'(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}x$ and $g'(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(x)}x$, $f'(0)\geqslant g'(0)$. But if you do the same thing with $x<0$, you deduce that $f'(0)\leqslant g'(0)$. Therefore, $f'(0)=g'(0)$.

Comment: Awesome! If I may ask, III is not necessary correct, right? I used x^2 sin(x^(-1)) to argue.

Comment: Right, III is not true in general.